# How can I cut text out of a svg in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

I'm not sure this is described well, but suppose I use the shape tool and create a square with a fill of Black.  Now I take the text tool and create the word "test" in the square, then convert it to vector by doing type>create outline.  At this point I have my canvas->black square>black text. I want to change the fill of the text to none, and have the white canvas show through, as if the text is now transparent.

I'm using Illustrator CC.

Thank you!

Comment: Attach a reference image of what you want..

Comment: No problem expand the strokes release compound path select everything and create compound path. But really many ways to catch fish here what do you expect the result to be used in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you just need to select both the outlined text and the square block. In window > pathfinder select the minus front button. This is the second button from the left under Shape Modes. This will subtract the text from the block leaving the white canvas to show through.

Hope this helps!